# Code commandButton dont work in datagrid but work in dataTab

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

Well i'm making a web, and i using primeface, but i was trying to do the example from the showcase of the datagrid with the commandButton command, but after 1 day of trying I fail, but i make the same code with dataTab and work so i'm lost i put the code if any of you can help me a little.

(technology used is tomcat 7, jsf 2.1 and primeface 3.2)

Here is the code of the dataTab

```
<p:dataTable id="juego" var="juego" value="#{juegoBean.files}">  

    <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:24%">  
        <h:outputText value="#{juego.id}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:24%">  
        <h:outputText value="#{juego.idUser.mail}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column style="width:4%">  
        <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:detalle" oncomplete="juegoDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{juego}" target="#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile}" />  
        </p:commandButton>  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

and this is the code of the dataGrid

```
<p:dataGrid  var="juego" value="#{juegoBean.files}" columns="3"  
    rows="12" paginator="true"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
    rowsPerPageTemplate="12,24,36">  

    <p:panel header="#{juego.id}" style="text-align:center">  
        <h:panelGrid style="width:100%">  
            <!--
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/.jpg"/>   
             <h:outputText value="#{juego.idUser.user}" />  

           <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:detalle" oncomplete="juegoDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{juego}" target="#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile}" />  
        </p:commandButton>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:panel>  

</p:dataGrid>
```

and this is the dialog how i'm trying to update

```
<p:dialog header="Information del archivo" widgetVar="juegoDialog" modal="true">  
    <p:outputPanel id="detalle" layout="block">  

          <p:tabView  id="tabView">  

                <p:tab id="general" title="General">  
                    <div id="descripcion">
                        <h3>Descripcion del juego</h3><br />

                        <p style="font-size: small;">#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.infoFile.description}</p><br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="categoria"> 
                        <h3>Categorias del Juego</h3><br />
                        <p style="font-size: small;">
                          </p><br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="clave"> 
                        <h3>Palabras clave</h3> <br />
                        <p style="font-size: small;">#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.infoFile.motCles}</p><br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="subido"> 
                        <h3>Esta archivo fue subido el:</h3> <br />
                        <p style="font-size: small;">#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.infoFile.dateUpload}</p>
                    </div>


                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="imagen" title="Imagenes del juego"> 
                    <div class="largo">
                        <ui:repeat var="imagen" value="#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.imageCollection}">
                   <img title="" alt="" src="#{imagen.root}" />
                    </ui:repeat>

                           </div>
                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="estadistica" title="Estadistica">  
                    <div>
                        <h3>Descargado: </h3><br />

                        <p style="font-size: small;">#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.telecharge}</p><br /> 
                    </div>
                    <div> 
                        <h3> Reputacion: </h3><br />
                        <p style="font-size: small;"></p><br /> 
                    </div>
                    <div> 
                        <h3> Ultima vez descargado: </h3><br />
                        <p style="font-size: small;">#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.infoFile.dateDernierTelechargement}</p><br /> 
                    </div>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="descargar" title="Descargar">  
                    <h3>  Descargar link </h3> <br/>

                    <br/>
                    <p style="font-size: small;"><a title=""  href="#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile.adresse}"  onclick="#{juegoBean.actualizarDescarga()}">Descargar</a></p>
                    <br/>

                </p:tab>  

            </p:tabView>  


    </p:outputPanel>  
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Update to latest PrimeFaces or wrap content of datagrid with a column. This is also documented in 3.2's user guide.

Comment: @cagatay thank is was the version of primeface

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `<p:colum>` after `<p:datagrid>`.

```
<p:dataGrid  var="juego" value="#{juegoBean.files}" columns="3"  
    rows="12" paginator="true"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
    rowsPerPageTemplate="12,24,36">  
<p:colum>
    <p:panel header="#{juego.id}" style="text-align:center">  
        <h:panelGrid style="width:100%">  
            <!-- -->
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/.jpg"/>   
             <h:outputText value="#{juego.idUser.user}" />  

           <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:detalle" oncomplete="juegoDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{juego}" target="#{juegoBean.seleccionadoFile}" />  
        </p:commandButton>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:panel>  
<p:colum>
</p:dataGrid>
```